# Privoxy blocks some .onion addresses and others not

Tags: privoxy

I know this is not the right channel, but I'll give it a try.

Privoxy blocks some .onion addresses and others not, In the older version this was not
I have already disabled all filters in the Privoxy config.
The `/var/log/privoxy/logfile` is empty.
How can I fix this?

---

```
System
```

> Kubuntu 20.04 LTS

---

```
Privoxy
```

> Privoxy version 3.0.32 (https://www.privoxy.org/)

---

```
ERROR
```

> Privoxy was unable to socks4a-forward your request through 127.0.0.1
> SOCKS request rejected or failed

---

When I bypass Privoxy and connect through Tor, the browser changes the address from `http://mail2tor2zyjdctd.onion/` to `https://www.mail2tor2zyjdctd.onion/`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should check out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI0Va.png. Source: https://www.privoxy.org/faq/misc.html

Comment: I read that a few years ago. My configuration is set properly.

Comment: Please provide the relevant configuration line from your Privoxy config: ```grep forward /etc/privoxy/config```.

Comment: I solved it. It's the Tor version. Im using Tor 0.2.9.9 (Tor HS V2:). Some sites are using the new version of Tor and the new protocol (Tor HS V3):, thats why i can not connect to this sites.